# Display letters one after the other for a looped sequence

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display multiple strings one after the other and I want the letters in each string to appear one at a time until the string is complete and it loops to the next string. Should run on a continuous loop.

```js
var example = ['IT Solutions', 'Professional Work Ethic'];
textSequence(0);
function textSequence(i) {
  if (example.length > i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = example[i];
      textSequence(++i);
    }, 4000);
  } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
    textSequence(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="sequence"></div>
```

Comment: What should happen after the last letter of the last string?

Comment: Loop back to the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer @adpro's answer, but here's an alternative that keeps your original array:

```
showLettersOf(
  ['IT Solutions', 'Professional Work Ethic'],
  document.querySelector('#sequence')
); 

function showLettersOf(arrayOfStrings, el) {
  var stringIndex=0, letterIndex=0, str="";
  return setInterval(function(){
    str += arrayOfStrings[stringIndex].charAt(letterIndex++);
    el.innerHTML = str;
    if (letterIndex >= arrayOfStrings[stringIndex].length){
      letterIndex=0;
      str="";
      if (++stringIndex >= arrayOfStrings.length) stringIndex=0;
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: It was unclear to me from the description if you wanted the full string to 'build' each time, e.g. "I", "IT", "IT ", "IT S", etc. or if you wanted each letter shown, e.g. "I", "T", " ", "S". I went with the former; if you wanted the latter, get rid of the `str` variable and just set the innerHTML to the `charAt()` each time.

Comment: Greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the strings, and then loop over them almost the same as you are. But you'll want to hold on to the `value` and pass it in recursively to keep track of what you have already.

This may not be exactly what you want, but I think you'll be able to figure it out by using this.

```js
var example = ['IT Solutions', 'Professional Work Ethic'];
var eString = example.join(' ');

textSequence(0, '');
function textSequence(i, value) {
  if (eString.length > i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      value += eString[i];
      document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = value;
      textSequence(++i, value);
    }, 100);
  } else if (eString.length == i) { // Loop
    textSequence(0, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="sequence"></div>
```